# Change Foundation Options in Meteor Application

Tags: css, meteor, zurb-foundation

I need to change where the breakpoints are for screen widths in terms of showing and hiding elements if the user's screen is in a particular size.

The project I'm working in is a Meteor project with the foundation CSS library.

I'm used to doing everything with PHP/JS with the occasional bootstrap, so what I would do normally is find the "_settings.scss" file and edit it like the doc says  and multiple forums, but where is this file? No where in me entire project file can I locate this file (or anything related to foundation, actually)

So, how do I edit the foundation settings when modifying a Meteor application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

which Foundation package do you use? 
Take a look at this package: https://atmospherejs.com/juliancwirko/zf5

Then ask me anything you need :)

Comment: This added the settings file, which a different version I was using didn't. Thanks!